# @Version Spring dont work with ObjectForm

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, version

I use @Version in one Java class and all Java classes extends of this. okey.
I also use objectForm. I use this because it is assumed that is more secure (I hide all `<form:hidden path="XX"/>` from JSP), but when I open two tabs in my browser, if I modify and safe the object in the two tabs, Spring does not check that the version is lower than that of the database and save it. If I not use object form, Spring alert me that the version is lower. Yes, objectForm is obligatory.

The idea is: I send ObjectForm at JSP. I modify the object from jsp and then, I return object form to controller. This, convert the objectForm to object and save the object.

Any idea?

Some pictures:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `@Version` annotation only works in Hibernate entity classes, that are directly saved into the database.

If you do the following the @Version will be validated, throwing an exception if an object with an invalid version is attempted to be saved in the database:

- read an entity from the database annotated with `@Version`
- copy entity data to a view layer object (including the version)
- modify it on the view layer
- on save button pressed, copy the form data including the version to a new entity object
- to save the new data, call `entityManager.merge()`
- the merge will trigger a database selection. if the version in the database is higher than the merged object you will get a `StaleObjectException`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but dont work.
I realize these steps. The only difference is that i don´t use entityManager.merge(project), i use "aRepository".save(project) which in turn calls a entityManager.merge(project).